# How to access and process @ViewChildren?

Tags: angular

I have below hierarchy of components:

**product-list.component.ts**

```
<product-list>  

    <ng-content></ng-content>

</product-list>
```

**product.component.ts**

```
<product>   

    <ng-content></ng-content>

</product>
```

**Demo.component.ts**

```
       <product-list>

                <product>

                    <product-rating></product-rating>

                </product>

        </product-list>

        <button label="Submit" (click)="submit()"></button>
```

On Submit, I have to access **product-rating** component and depending on rating have to change the color of corresponding **product** component. What is the best way to access and process this?

**Demo.component.ts**

```
@ViewChildren(ProductRatingComponent) ratings: QueryList<ProductRatingComponent>;
```

**product.component.ts**

```
@ViewChildren(ProductRatingComponent) ratings: QueryList<ProductRatingComponent>;
```

Is there any better way to access **product-rating** component?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have what looks like a relatively complex component structure, you can still achieve what you want to with standard `@Output` and `@Input` events and properties.

Your starting point is to decide which component is "controlling" everything. In your case it's the demo component. Demo component is deciding what the component hierarchy is. Next you need to work out the desired flow of data. In your case, it will look a bit like this:

product-rating -> demo -> product

A rating is determined by `product-rating`, and needs to get to `product` via the controller.

So you need to add an `@Output` event to product rating that the control can subscribe to:

```
@Output() ratingChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

// this is some event handler that handles the user-driven rating change
onRatingChange(): void {
  // Emit the rating. I am guessing here that the rating is stored in some property
  // It might come into this function as an event arg - that's up to your design.
  this.ratingChange.emit(this.rating);
}
```

So now the demo component can handle the rating change events and send it to the product:

**demo.component.html**

```
<product [rating]="rating">
  <product-rating (ratingChange)="onRatingChange($event)"></product-rating>
</product>
```

**demo.component.ts**

```
rating: number;

onRatingChange(rating: number): void {
  this.rating = rating;
}
```

Comment: I can't do any change in <product-rating> component. It is coming from other npm module. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can create your own wrapper for it and handle any events from the third party component in there.